# Bind variable initialization in constructor c++

Tags: c++, oop

I should get the type of the descendant class, the descendant class should initialize it with my type, but I can forget to do it.
Ideally, I would like to make the compiler unable to compile the code if I had not initialized this variable in the constructor of the derived class.
How can i do this?
Example code:

```
#include <iostream>

enum class AnimalType : int {
  kDog = 2, // not null
  kCat
};

// Abstract animal
class Animal {
public:
  AnimalType GetAnimalType() {
    return this->animal_type;
  }

  // Example virtual method
  virtual void Sound() = 0;

protected:
  AnimalType animal_type;
};

class Dog : public Animal {
public:
  Dog() {
    this->animal_type = AnimalType::kDog;
  }

  void Sound() override {
    printf("Woof!\n");
  }
};

class Cat : public Animal {
public:
  Cat() {
    //this->animal_type = AnimalType::kCat;
    // I can forget to do it
    // How can I make it required?
  }

  void Sound() override {
    printf("Meow!\n");
  }
};

int main() {
  Animal* dog = new Dog();
  Animal* cat = new Cat();

  dog->Sound();
  cat->Sound();

  printf("Dog animal type: %d\n", dog->GetAnimalType());

  // undefined behavior, because animal_type is not initialized
  printf("Cat animal type: %d\n", cat->GetAnimalType());

  delete dog;
  delete cat;

  system("pause");
  return 0;
}
```

Output: [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Af1l.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create proper constructor for `Animal`:

```
class Animal {
public:
  explicit Animal(AnimalType animal_type) : animal_type(animal_type) {}
  virtual ~Animal() = default;

  AnimalType GetAnimalType() const { return this->animal_type; }

  // Example virtual method
  virtual void Sound() = 0;

private:
  AnimalType animal_type;
};
```

With usage:

```
class Dog : public Animal {
public:
  Dog() : Animal(AnimalType::kDog) {}

  void Sound() override { printf("Woof!\n"); }
};
```